# SQL Join query with filter condition : performance

Tags: sql, oracle11g

I want to join a couple of tables but filter a particular type from 'A' table. Which is the better query from the following two queries (is there a better approach?) or is there no difference cause of query optimizer ?

When filter condition is given in 'WHERE' clause:

```
SELECT .. FROM A a JOIN B b ON a.id=b.id JOIN C c on a.id = c.id...<other joins>...WHERE a.col='SOME_VAL';
```

The filter condition is given inside 'ON':

```
SELECT .. FROM A a JOIN B b ON a.id=b.id AND a.col='SOME_VAL' JOIN C c on a.id = c.id...<other joins>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With INNER JOINs there is no resulting performance difference, which you can check using EXPLAIN (both forms of your query should yield the same plan).

The benefit of using the WHERE clause can often be readability.  When combined with a multi-line layout.  (I strongly recommend Not keeping all your SQL as one long line.)

```
SELECT
  stuff
FROM 
  foo
INNER JOIN
  bar
    ON  (join predicates here)
WHERE
  (static filters here)
```

The reason it becomes easier to read (and maintain) is that the join predicates now expressly only describe the Relationship between the tables.  The query still runs correctly without the WHERE clause, but returns a larger set.